# How to validate gridview dropdown values using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a grid with dropdown it populate value As Room No 1-5 and i have maximum occupany if user select more than the occupancy it should show alert.example Room max occupancy 2.i have multiple user if room no 1 got selected by two user then 3rd user select means it should validate.

Comment: Could you explain where your code is not working and provide us some of the attempts you did.

Comment: i did javascript  validation with gridview foreach loop ,but i cant able to store value and validate

Comment: there is no better solution !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function ddlchange(ddl) {
            ddlvalue = ddl.value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "PageName.aspx?SelectValue=" + ddlvalue,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "" && data != null) {
                        if (data = "true")
                            alert("your Msg");
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Error Occured, Try Again');
                }
            });
        }
```

call above function with adding below line to your dropdownlist
onchange="ddlchange(this);"